# VHDL - Xilinx ISE crashing during synthesis

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to VHDL and am having a bit of an issue with the synthesis tool crashing when I have certain stuff in my code (developing in Xilinx ISE).

Below is the gist of what is making the program crash.

```
signal enteredDigit1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin

u3: entity work.module port map (x,y, enteredDigit1)

process(asyncClock, enteredDigit1) begin
    ssegDigit <= enteredDigit1
end process
```

If I do the ssegDigit <= enteredDigit1 outside that process, its fine. However due to me needing to write an asynchronous bit of code, I figured it would be easier to keep track of states and such in a process.

Any ideas why it would just crash? I get no indication from the program console.

EDIT: It seems to be crashing because I'm assigning ssegDigit a new value. If I instead give enteredDigit1 to a variable in the process it compiles

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the error message and/or the declaration for `ssegDigit` it may be impossible to provide a definitive answer.

This analyzes:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity module is
    port ( 
        signal x:               in   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        signal y:               in   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        signal enteredDigit1:   out  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of module is
begin

end architecture;    

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ssegDigit_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of ssegDigit_tb is

    signal asyncClock:     std_logic;
    signal x:              std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal y:              std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

    signal ssegDigit:      std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

    signal enteredDigit1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);


begin

u3: entity work.module port map (x,y, enteredDigit1);

    process(asyncClock, enteredDigit1) 
    begin
        ssegDigit <= enteredDigit1;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Notice that `ssegDigit` has the same index range of `enteredDigit1`, and I corrected the declaration for `enteredDigit1` which was:

```
signal enteredDigit1 : std_logic_vector(3 down 0);
```

Where the VHDL reserved word `downto` was not complete and should be:

```
    signal enteredDigit1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
```

Without knowing your exact methodology for causing the ISE tool to crash there's an outside possibility that it's parser isn't robust enough.

In general a simulator's analyzer is going to be more robust than one found in a synthesis tool.  Synthesizers are written anticipating a valid VHDL design specification, which also points to the utility of validating your design before synthesis.

If neither the declaration for `ssegDigit` having a matching element for each element in `enteredDigit1` nor fixing the  reserved word `downto` in declaration for enteredDigit1 is your problem, by definition you haven't provided enough information.  Also notice the semicolon following the assignment statement in the process and after `end process`.

Let us know, and elaborate the question if needed.

Noted you corrected the `downto` in your example but not the missing semicolons.

***After your comment:***

> ... The sseg digits are declared as you expected, and port mapped to the same range. I was thinking maybe its a case of the synthesizer flipping out because the signal enteredDigit1 is being modified in a few places. Any idea why it would work outside the process? synchronous issues?

It appears that `ssegDigit` is declared as a signal and connected to a port.  This points to the futility of playing twenty questions in comments, where each time around a bit more information is revealed (we'd eventually get a message suggesting moving dialogs to a wiki chat if nothing else).

Perhaps you could show port declarations including mode, signal declarations for the involved elements and any assignment statements for the signals particularly `enteredDigit1`.

It might also be useful for you to demonstrate the indications leading you to conclude the synthesis tool 'crashing'.

See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , Help others reproduce the problem, "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example" ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: it actually was downto, just a typo. The sseg digits are declared as you expected, and port mapped to the same range. I was thinking maybe its a case of the synthesizer flipping out because the signal enteredDigit1 is being modified in a few places. 

Any idea why it would work outside the process? synchronous issues?

Comment: If you were to eliminate the sensitivity list, add a wait statement as the last statement of the process of the form `wait on asyncClock, enteredDigit1;` your process statement would be identical to the equivalent process statement used for the concurrent statement for except for `asyncClock` which does not appear on the right hand side of an assignment statement. If it's not used remove it. I'd imagine a synthesizer (which operates on the equivalent of an equivalent process) shouldn't crash because of an extra sensitivity list element.